# How do I apply modifications to a locally scoped range and return it?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

The code below, when compiled under g++-11.3 using `--std=c++20 -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` and executed, produces a bizarre runtime error about iterators. I'm not exactly sure what it means but I suspect it has something to do with the vector `range` going out of scope when `test()` returns: `range` doesn't get moved or copied, rather whatever it is the pipe operator returns just retains a reference to `range`.

```cpp
#include <ranges>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

auto to_unordered_set(auto && range) {
    using r_type = std::ranges::range_value_t<decltype(range)>;
    auto common = range | std::views::common;
    return std::unordered_set<r_type>(std::ranges::begin(common), std::ranges::end(common));
}

auto test() {
    std::vector<int> range {1,2,3,4,5};
    return range | std::ranges::views::transform([](auto x) { return x%2; });
}

int main() {
    auto y = to_unordered_set(test());
    return 0;
}

/*
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.3.0/include/c++/11.3.0/debug/safe_iterator.h:195:
In function:
    __gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<_Iterator, _Sequence, 
    _Category>::_Safe_iterator(__gnu_debug::_Safe_iterator<_Iterator, 
    _Sequence, _Category>&&) [with _Iterator = 
    __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::__cxx1998::vector<int, 
    std::allocator<int> > >; _Sequence = std::__debug::vector<int>; 
    _Category = std::forward_iterator_tag]

Error: attempt to copy-construct an iterator from a singular iterator.

Objects involved in the operation:
    iterator "this" @ 0x0x7ffea2b7a8c0 {
      type = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::__cxx1998::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > (mutable iterator);
      state = singular;
    }
    iterator "other" @ 0x0x7ffea2b7a820 {
      type = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::__cxx1998::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > (mutable iterator);
      state = singular;
      references sequence with type 'std::__debug::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >' @ 0x0x7ffea2b7a8b0
    }
*/
```

Is there anyway to get something like this to work? I basically want to transform / filter / join / etc.. a range and return it (a copy/move of the entire thing gets returned, both the range and whatever modifications get applied to it).

Comment: IIRC ranges are lazy.  When test ends the source goes out of scope, taking everything else out with it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, since the `std::vector` itself is `common_range`, `transform_view` will also be `common_range`, so using `views::common` here is redundant.

Second and more important, `range` is a local variable, so it will be destroyed once it leaves `test()`, which makes `test()` return a `transform_view` that holds a dangling pointer.

> Is there anyway to get something like this to work?

Thanks to [P2415](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2415r2.html), you can directly return a `transform_view` applied to a *rvalue* `vector`, which will construct an `owning_view` that transfers ownership of the original `vector`'s contents to itself, which will no longer cause dangling.

```
#include <ranges>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>

auto to_unordered_set(auto && range) {
  using r_type = std::ranges::range_value_t<decltype(range)>;
  return std::unordered_set<r_type>(
           std::ranges::begin(range), std::ranges::end(range));
}

auto test() {
  std::vector<int> range {1,2,3,4,5};
  return std::move(range) | 
    std::ranges::views::transform([](auto x) { return x%2; });
}

int main() {
  auto y = to_unordered_set(test());
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8fWfvdKcb)

Comment: Thank you. I had tried this originally but it didn't work. I guess it's only supported in g++12.